# Find the continuous interval and give an id

Tags: pandas, database, dataframe, group-by

I would like to group each continuous region and to each region an id

For examplethe following data set

```
df = pd.Series(data = [0,1,1,1,2,2,2,16,17,18,18,18,18,1,1,1,1,2,2,200,201,3,4])
```

the output should be

```
pd.Series(data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4])
```

I tried to use that code but it didn't work,

```
df= pd.concat([df, (df==0).cumsum()], axis = 1, keys = ['val', 'flag']>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to detect the points where the change is greater than 1. You can achieve that with a chain of simple arithmetic operations:

```
df.sub(df.shift(1)).abs().gt(1).cumsum()
```

Comment: Hi Nuri , thank u,  yes but it is not clear to me the line of code you wrote it doesn't give me the right output.

Comment: For the above sample dataframe, I was able to reproduce the expected output. Could you share the exact form of the dataframe and the expected output?